# JSF error - IllegalStateException: PWC3999: Cannot create a session after the response has been committed

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, facelets

I am new to JSF and I am building a application created with facelets.
Here is my template
master.xhtml

```
<body id="body">
 <form id="frmmaster">
        <div id="pg-nav-bg">
            <div class="wrapper clear">
                <div class="footer clear">
                    <div class="footerContent">Help Des</div>
                </div>
                <div id="pg-nav">
                    <ul class="nav sf-js-enabled">
                        <li class="page_item" id="liHomr">
                            <a href="#" title="Home">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="page_item" id="liFreeSearch">
                            <a href="#" title="Free Search" >Free Search</a>  
                        </li>
                        <li class="page_item" id="liMasterSearch">      
                            <a href="#"  title="Search">Search</a> 
                        </li>
                        <li class="page_item" id="liAdvanceSearch">
                            <a href="#" title="Advanced Search">Advanced Search</a> 
                        </li>
                        <li class="page_item" id="liCharts">
                            <a href="#" title="Charts" >Charts</a>  <!-- 
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="wrapper clear">
            <div class="Welcome ">
                <div class="welcome">
                     Welcome! &nbsp;<strong>Searcher</strong>
                    &nbsp; | &nbsp;
                    <strong >
                        [ <a title="Change Password" href="" style="color: #FFFFFF;">Change Password</a> ]
                        [ <h:commandLink id="lbSignOut" value="Sign Out" onclick="lbSignOut_Click"  styleClass="color: #FFFFFF;"></h:commandLink> ]
                    </strong>
                </div>
                <br class="clear" />
                <div>
                    <label id="lblMessage"></label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="wrapper big" >
            <div id="header" class="clear">
                <img src="../../images/logo.png" class="image" alt=""/>
                <div class="logo">
                    <div id="title" >M - 11</div>
                    <div id="version">V 0.8</div>
                    <div id="description">Helps in finding the right person</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Here I included facelet -->
            <ui:include src="../SearchPages/MasterSearch.xhtml"/> 

        </div>
   </form>
</body>

</html>
```

## Now the below file is my composition file that I included here in master.xhtml i-e

MasterSearch.xhtml

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
<div id="sidebar">
            <ul>
                <li class="widget">
                    <table>   
                    <h:form> 
                        <tr><td>Service Number</td>
                            <td>
                            <h:inputText id="txtMasterServiceNumber" styleClass="text-box" value="#{masterSearch.serviceNumber}" requiredMessage="enter value">
                            <f:validateRegex pattern="[A-Za-z0-9]{1,40}"/>
                            </h:inputText>
                            <h:message for="txtMasterServiceNumber" />

                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Rank</td>
                            <td><h:selectOneMenu id="cboMasterRank" value="#{masterSearch.rank}" styleClass="select-field">
                                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="--Please Select--" itemValue="medium" />
                                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="A" itemValue="medium" />
                                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="B" itemValue="basic" />
                                            <f:selectItem itemLabel="C" itemValue="premium" />
                                            </h:selectOneMenu></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Full Name</td>
                            <td>
                            <h:inputText id="txtMasterFullName" styleClass="text-box" value="#{masterSearch.fullName}" validatorMessage="Please enter a valid name.">
                            <f:validateRegex pattern="^([A-Za-z])*$" />
                            <h:message for="txtMasterFullName" styleClass="Error" /></h:inputText>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>CNIC Number</td>
                            <td><h:inputText id="txtMasterCNIC" value="#{masterSearch.CNICNumber}"  styleClass="text-box">
                            <f:validateRegex pattern="^([A-Za-z])*$" />
                            <h:message for="txtMasterFullName" styleClass="Error" />
                            </h:inputText>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Phone No.</td>
                            <td><h:inputText id="txtMasterPhoneNo" value="#{masterSearch.phoneNumber}"  styleClass="text-box"></h:inputText>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Email Address</td>
                            <td><h:inputText id="txtMasterEmail" value="#{masterSearch.emailAddress}"  styleClass="text-box"></h:inputText>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2" align="right">
                            <h:commandButton id="btnMasterSearch"  type="submit" value="Search" styleClass="submitButton"  action="#{masterSearch.findPerson}"></h:commandButton>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        </h:form>
                   </table>
                </li>
            </ul>
                <img src="../../images/loader.gif" alt="" style="vertical-align:middle;margin:2px;"/>Loading...
        </div>

    </div>
    <script src="../../Scripts/searchexternal.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

MasterSearch.java Which is a bean

```
public class MasterSearch {

    long serviceNumber;
    String rank;
    String fullName;
    String CNICNumber;
    String phoneNumber;
    String emailAddress;

    public long getServiceNumber() {
        return serviceNumber;
    }
    public void setServiceNumber(long serviceNumber) {
        this.serviceNumber = serviceNumber;
    }
    public String getRank() {
        return rank;
    }
    public void setRank(String rank) {
        this.rank = rank;
    }
    public String getFullName() {
        return fullName;
    }
    public void setFullName(String fullName) {
        this.fullName = fullName;
    }
    public String getCNICNumber() {
        return CNICNumber;
    }
    public void setCNICNumber(String cNICNumber) {
        CNICNumber = cNICNumber;
    }
    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }
    public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }
    public String getEmailAddress() {
        return emailAddress;
    }
    public void setEmailAddress(String emailAddress) {
        this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
    }

    public String findPerson(){

        return "personfound";

    }

}
```

faces-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<faces-config
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"

    version="2.0">

    <application>
        <el-resolver>
            org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver
        </el-resolver>
    </application>

<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>masterSearch</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>
            MasterSearch
        </managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>

<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>masterResult</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>
            com.delta.resultbeans.MasterSearchResult
        </managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>

<navigation-rule>
    <description>Navigation from the MasterSearch</description>
    <from-view-id>/WebPages/SearchPages/MasterSearch.xhtml</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>personfound</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/WebPages/SearchPages/found.jsp</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>personnotfound</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/notfound.jsp</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
</faces-config>
```

Now When I run this code (actually masterp.xhtml) it shows perfect output and loads accuratley but it throws an exception in console i-e

```
SEVERE: Error Rendering View[/WebPages/MasterPage/master.xhtml]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: PWC3999: Cannot create a session after the response has been committed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.doGetSession(Request.java:2885)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getSession(Request.java:2582)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getSession(RequestFacade.java:920)
    at com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.getSession(ExternalContextImpl.java:155)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.ServerSideStateHelper.writeState(ServerSideStateHelper.java:175)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.ResponseStateManagerImpl.writeState(ResponseStateManagerImpl.java:122)
    at com.sun.faces.application.StateManagerImpl.writeState(StateManagerImpl.java:166)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.WriteBehindStateWriter.flushToWriter(WriteBehindStateWriter.java:225)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:419)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1542)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:849)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:746)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1045)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:228)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

INFO: Exception when handling error trying to reset the response.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: PWC3999: Cannot create a session after the response has been committed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.doGetSession(Request.java:2885)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getSession(Request.java:2582)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getSession(RequestFacade.java:920)
    at com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.getSession(ExternalContextImpl.java:155)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.ServerSideStateHelper.writeState(ServerSideStateHelper.java:175)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.ResponseStateManagerImpl.writeState(ResponseStateManagerImpl.java:122)
    at com.sun.faces.application.StateManagerImpl.writeState(StateManagerImpl.java:166)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.WriteBehindStateWriter.flushToWriter(WriteBehindStateWriter.java:225)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:419)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1542)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:849)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:746)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1045)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:228)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

WARNING: StandardWrapperValve[Faces Servlet]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: PWC3999: Cannot create a session after the response has been committed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.doGetSession(Request.java:2885)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getSession(Request.java:2582)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getSession(RequestFacade.java:920)
    at com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.getSession(ExternalContextImpl.java:155)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.ServerSideStateHelper.writeState(ServerSideStateHelper.java:175)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.ResponseStateManagerImpl.writeState(ResponseStateManagerImpl.java:122)
    at com.sun.faces.application.StateManagerImpl.writeState(StateManagerImpl.java:166)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.WriteBehindStateWriter.flushToWriter(WriteBehindStateWriter.java:225)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:419)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1542)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:849)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:746)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1045)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:228)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

And I think due to this it is not submitting action of my button

`<h:commandButton id="btnMasterSearch"  type="submit" value="Search" styleClass="submitButton"  action="#{masterSearch.findPerson}">` present in `MasterSearch.xhtml`.I found on SO that people had that problem but I am unable to find and understand a good solution.
please help thanks

Comment: I don't understand why you mix plain HTML with Facelets.

Comment: "Cannot create a session after the response has been committed" it seems after page response complete, somewhere in your code you are trying to create session. I would suggest check backing beans.

Comment: right but what should I check in my backing beans? I mean they are just beans having getter setters.. @thinksteep

Comment: Don't you have beans with business logic?

Comment: Not yet -I am just nevigating - let me add my bean and faces-config.xml

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a known bug in Mojarra. It has been reported as issues [2215](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-2215) and [2277](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-2277) and has been fixed since Mojarra 2.1.8. So if you upgrade to at least 2.1.8, then this problem should disappear.

The cause of this problem can be explained as follows: Mojarra is trying to postpone the session creation as much as possible. The session should only be created at the moment when it is *really* needed. Among others, when the JSF view state of the `<h:form>` needs to be written, which normally happens during rendering of the closing `</h:form>`. However, on relatively large pages wherein the closing `</h:form>` appears *after* 2KB of written HTML, then it's too late to create the session. To create a session the server namely needs to set a cookie. However, to set a cookie, the response should not have been committed (the cookie namely needs to go in the response header). A server is by default configured to flush the response on every 2KB of written HTML.

As said, this issue is been fixed since Mojarra 2.1.8. You can download the latest version [here](http://javaserverfaces.java.net).

Comment: thx @BalusC - I am new to JSF so i didn't understand that why this mojarra issue came in my application as I am using glassfish 3.1.2 and i didn't include any jar for JSF as glassfish has built in support for this. So if I am not using mojarra then it came? and for the resolvation what should I do now after downloading its 2.1.11 version...should i include that javax.faces-2.1.11.jar in my classpath?

Comment: JSF is bundled in Glassfish. Glassfish 3.1.2 uses Mojarra 2.1.6. Just replace the `javax.faces.jar` file in `/glassfish/modules` folder with the newer version.

Comment: love you man - you are awesome :) As that code is not available to me yet but I hope when I will try this it will be OK :) :*

Comment: You're welcome. By the way, if you don't have full admin control over the Glassfish server installation, then you can also upgrade JSF by placing the newer `javax.faces.jar` file in webapp's own `/WEB-INF/lib` folder and editing the `/WEB-INF/glassfish-web.xml` file to add the following two new entries: `<class-loader delegate="false" /><property name="useBundledJsf" value="true" />`.

Comment: Is this property will enforce my app to use my project jsf.faces.xx.jar instead of glassfish jar ? As sometimes we have such type of issues...

Comment: Thank @BalusC It helped me too. How come you know all this? Do you spend all the time learning or do you have any other activies as well like Sports , games etc. ?