# GlassFish 3.1.2.2 JSF upgrade

Tags: jsf, glassfish

We upgraded JSF from 2.1.6 to 2.1.22 to solve this problem: [JSF error - IllegalStateException: PWC3999: Cannot create a session after the response has been committed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11877420/jsf-error-illegalstateexception-pwc3999-cannot-create-a-session-after-the-re)

And it works. But the change of JSF version caused another problem: some components are not found in view and GlassFish threw a stacktrace with two exceptions. The first:

```
javax.faces.FacesException: Cannot find component with identifier ":previewForm" referenced from "indexForm:publicacoesDt:j_idt112".
    at org.primefaces.util.ComponentUtils.findClientIds(ComponentUtils.java:271)
    at org.primefaces.util.AjaxRequestBuilder.addIds(AjaxRequestBuilder.java:102)
    at org.primefaces.util.AjaxRequestBuilder.update(AjaxRequestBuilder.java:90)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.buildAjaxRequest(CoreRenderer.java:196)
    at org.primefaces.component.commandlink.CommandLinkRenderer.encodeEnd(CommandLinkRenderer.java:64)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:905)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeRecursive(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:312)
    ...
```

And the second:

```
PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: CDATA tags may not nest
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlResponseWriter.startCDATA(HtmlResponseWriter.java:664)
    at javax.faces.context.ResponseWriterWrapper.startCDATA(ResponseWriterWrapper.java:172)
    at javax.faces.context.PartialResponseWriter.startError(PartialResponseWriter.java:342)
    at org.primefaces.context.PrimePartialResponseWriter.startError(PrimePartialResponseWriter.java:155)
    at com.sun.faces.context.AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.handlePartialResponseError(AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.java:200)
    at com.sun.faces.context.AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.handle(AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.java:124)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:119)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
    ...
```

The component with identifier "indexForm:publicacoesDt:j_idt112" is a commandLink from PrimeFaces and the ":previewForm" is a JSF form. This problem happens when a commandButton, that updates a form with the commandLink, is fired. But just in the second submission, the first is successful.

Anyone know why this problem happens?

Comment: Could you provide the code?